# Using regex how to perform string match to get a different date format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two dateString formats like `:date-f1:+2` and `:date-f2:-1`, if the incoming string is in `date-f1:+2` format,  I need to console.log as  processedDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), but if the incoming string is in `:date-f2:-1` format, I need to console.log as processedDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"). I have tried the below, but getting an exception `Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"`, could someone please advise;

```
let dateString = ":date-f1:+2";  // or ":date-f2:-1"

    function datesParse(dateString) {
        
    let matchFormat = dateString.match(/^:date-f1:(|):date-f2:(?:([\-\+])([0-9]+)+)?$/);

        let processedDate = moment();
        if (matchFormat[1] === "-") {
            processedDate = processedDate.subtract(matchFormat[2], 'days');
            console.log("Date::"+processedDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
        } else if (matchFormat[1] === "+") {
            processedDate = processedDate.add(matchFormat[2], 'days');
            console.log("Date::"+processedDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
        } else if (matchFormat[1] === "-") {
            processedDate = processedDate.subtract(matchFormat[2], 'days');
            console.log("Date::"+processedDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        } else if (matchFormat[1] === "+") {
            processedDate = processedDate.add(matchFormat[2], 'days');
            console.log("Date::"+processedDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        }
        
    }
    
    datesParse(dateString);
```

Comment: Your OR is wrong..shouldn't it be `(:date-f1:|:date-f2:)` ?

Comment: If there are only two specific formats(`:date-f1:+2` and `:date-f2:-1`) where literally nothing changes, then instead of regex use `if else` else for checking. Using regex here seems wasteful.

Comment: Agreed, but if we are using `includes` like below, then we need to check `-f1` and `+` or `-` operator at the same time ..right ? 
`let word = "-f1" 
let operator = "+" 
if (dateString.includes(word) && dateString.includes(operator)) { ....`

Comment: So the operators after f1/f2 changes? like can there be 'f1:+number' and 'f1:-number' the same for f2)? and you want to capture the operator and the word? These weren't mentioned in the question, so please update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your regex and also added named capture groups, try this: `/^:date-(?<word>f[12]):(?:(?<operator>[-+])(?<number>[0-9]+)+)?$/gm`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/cNNHA5/1

With capture groups you can access each of those captured elements easily:

```js
let line = ':date-f1:+2';

let pattern = /^:date-(?<word>f[12]):(?:(?<operator>[-+])(?<number>[0-9]+)+)?$/gm

let match = pattern.exec(line)

console.log('word', match.groups.word)
console.log('operator', match.groups.operator)
console.log('number', match.groups.number)
```

and use them for checking like:

```js
if (dateString.includes(match.groups.word) && dateString.includes(match.groups.operator))
```

so you dont have to create extra vars `word` and `operator`.

Comment: Thank you, I have upvoted and accepted, how can we build a regex patter

Comment: @soccerway to create a regex literal you can do `const re = /ab+c/gm;` to create a constructor use `const re = new RegExp('ab+c');`. Read more about regex here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions